# Rspec: "undefined local variable or method `controller_class_path' for #<RspecControllerGenerator"

Tags: rspec

I keep getting this error when I try to run

```
./script/generate rspec_controller foo
undefined local variable or method `controller_class_path' for <RspecControllerGenerator:0x25b046c>
```

I am using Rails 2.3.3, rspec 1.2.8, rspec-rails 1.2.7.1

The offending line is line 15 in rspec-rails/generators/rspec_controller/rspec_controller_generator.rb

m.directory File.join('spec/routing', controller_class_path)

The controller generator fails to run.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same anomaly.  My work-around was to run "./script/generate rspec_scaffold foo..."

I added this anomaly as a [bug](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8995-rails-plugins/tickets/65-rspec-undefined-local-variable-or-method-controller_class_path-for-rspeccontrollergenerator#ticket-65-2) at Rails Lighthouse